# Keras Loss: Allow multiple y_true values to be correct

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm, loss-function

I'm doing categorical sequence prediction with an LSTM layer and a fully connected layer. I match the current input with the "correct" output, an element in the sequence that occurs later.

I want to be more flexible about what is considered "correct." I want to consider a few sequence values around the y_true to be considered correct also. 
For example given the sequence [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,...] if I want to predict 5 elements in advance then for input timestep 0, I pass in 'a' and want to predict 'f', 'g', or 'h'. I want all three of these elements to be considered correct.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Keras (or Tensorflow if need be)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multilabel classification doh..
Using binary crossentropy as loss and having an appropriate y_label vector with ones for correct labels and 0's otherwise should work.